# Object Being Overwritten in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have an issue with Multiprocessing in Python and I am thoroughly stumped.  The outline of the script I am working on is as follows:

1. Create queues to pass data between processes
2. Create a TF-IDF vectorizer and train it on some text
3. Create some worker processes that wait for input from a queue
4. Pass some data to the queue to find similar data points using cosine similarity
5. Wait for all processes to send the finished signal then exit

The code is below, the problem I am getting is that at some point during execution the "queue_in" object is being replaced with a sparse matrix.  I'm confused on how this is happening because I never explicitly rewrite the value of queue_in.  A second question I have is that during execution the line that prints out "Hello from process {os.getpid()}" is executed multiple times.  I thought that once the child process started executing the function it would be in the infinite loop until it received the 'poison pill' from the queue_in.

I've googled this and nothing has come up.  I'm also sorta kinda new to multiprocessing so any help to understand why the queue_in object is being replaced with something else would be super helpful.

Stack trace below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer as TFIDF
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import time

model_dir = '/home/hma94128/bert_base_uncased/'
udata_dir = '/home/hma94128/synthetic_data/unlabeled_data.csv/unlabeled.csv'
rdata_dir = '/home/hma94128/training_data_and_labels_no_other.csv'
chunksize=100
workers = 5
row_limit = 200
cutoff=.8

def stream_text():
    '''Streams single line of text for training the TFIDF vectorizer'''
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    with pd.read_csv(rdata_dir, chunksize=1) as reader:
        for chunk in reader:
            text = chunk['text'].tolist()[0]
            text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(x) for x in text.split(' ')]
            text = ' '.join(text)
            yield text
            
#TODO: function to calculate cosine similarity and capture rows greater than cutoff, then write to file
def cosine_similarity(queue_in,
                      queue_out,
                      cutoff=cutoff,):
    '''Funcion that iterates over the reference dataframe
    to identify similar datapoints in unlabeled_data'''
    print(f'Hello from process {os.getpid()}')
    while True:
        rows_written = 0
        data_package = queue_in.get()
        print('Got chunk!')
        #if poison pill comes through then terminate
        if data_package == None:
            queue_out.put(1)
            break
        row = data_package[0]
        unlabeled_data = data_package[1]
        for idx in row.index:
            #get text data
            text_data = row.at[idx,'text']
            #get labels
            labels = row.iloc[idx:idx+1,3:]
            record_id = row.at[idx,'record_id']
            #transform text to vector
            print('Transforming text')
            reference_vector = tfidf.transform([text_data])
            #make list of text to pass to model
            unlabeled_text = unlabeled_data['text_data'].tolist()
            unlabeled_vectors = tfidf.transform(unlabeled_text)
            #calculate cosine similiarity
            similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(unlabeled_vectors, reference_vector)
            cidx = np.nonzero(similarity_matrix>cutoff)[0]
            if cidx.shape[0]>0:
                #increment number of rows written
                rows_written += cidx.shape[0]
                print(f'Found {similarity_matrix[np.nonzero(similarity_matrix>cutoff)[0]].shape[0]}!')
                #determine where the CS score is higher than cutoff
                #np.nonzero()[0] returns the indices where the criteria is met and get text
                close_enough = unlabeled_data[['text_data']].iloc[cidx,:]

                #make block of labels to concatenate
                labels = pd.concat([labels for x in range(close_enough.shape[0])])
                close_enough['record_id'] = record_id
                cloe_enough['source'] = 'synthetic'
                close_enough['cosine_sim'] = similarity_matrix[cidx]
                close_enough = close_enough.rename(columns={'text_data':'text'})
                output = pd.concat([close_enough, labels], axis=1)
                
                #if data already written then no header
                if rows_written > 0:
                    output.to_csv(f'synthetic_data_output_{os.getpid()}.csv',index=False, header=False, mode='a')
                else:
                    output.to_csv(f'synthetic_data_output_{os.getpid()}.csv',index=False, mode='a')
                print('Waiting to work on new block!')
            else:
                print(f'{os.getpid()} found no rows :( moving on!')
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #make queues
    print('Making queues')
    queue_in = mp.Queue()
    queue_out = mp.Queue()

    #make tfidf vectorizer
    print('Making TFIDF vectorizer')
    tfidf = TFIDF(stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,1), max_df=.9, max_features=1000)
    stream = stream_text()
    tfidf = tfidf.fit(stream)

    #start worker processes
    print('Starting workers')
    processes = []
    for n in range(workers):
        p = mp.Process(target=cosine_similarity, args=(queue_in, queue_out))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    print('Reading in data to iterate over rows...')
    rdata = pd.read_csv(rdata_dir)
    print('Feeding jobs')
    for idx in tqdm(range(rdata.shape[0])):
        row_count = 0
        row = rdata.iloc[idx:idx+1,:]
        with pd.read_csv(udata_dir, on_bad_lines='skip', chunksize=chunksize) as reader:
            for chunk in reader:
                #don't overload it
                while queue_in.qsize()>20:
                    time.sleep(1)
                data_block = (row, chunk)
                queue_in.put(data_block)

    finished = 0
    print('Waiting for cleanup')
    while finsihed < workers:
        output = queue_out.get()
        finished += output
    print('Done!')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3clq.png)

I've tried googling why the queue_in object could be replaced but no luck.  I've also tried using a mp.Manager() and then using that to create queues with manager.Queue() but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite clear that you have two functions called `cosine_similarity`:

1. one imported from `sklearn.metrics.pairwise`
2. another one defined by yourself and used to start Process

Since the second one is defined later, it override the first one.

So when you invoke `cosine_similarity` inside your new Process, you've actually invoked the `cosine_similarity` function defined by yourself, instead of the imported one.

Thus the solution is simple. Just rename your own `cosine_similarity` to something else, such as `calculate_cosine_similarity`.

Comment: My man, thank you so much!  I knew it was something simple like that.  I'll give it a go and get back to you!